# Rspec Helper method with same name getting executed by Rails Controller while running tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails

I have the following code in my ApplicationController :

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 protect_from_forgery
 include SessionsHelper  
end
```

app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper
 def sign_in(user)
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token]= user.remember_token
  self.current_user = user 
 end
end
```

I'm using rspec-rails and have used a helper method 'sign_in' in my utilities.rb file:
spec/support/utilities.rb

```
def sign_in(user)
 visit signin_path
 fill_in "Email",with:user.email
 fill_in "Password",with:user.password
 click_button 'Sign in'
 cookies[:remember_token]=user.remember_token
end
```

My static_pages_spec looks like this :

```
 describe "When signed in" do
  let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
  before do
    sign_in user
  end
  describe "When no lists are present" do

    it "should show message asking to create list" do
      page.should have_selector("div",text:"You have no lists ! Create a list now !")
    end
  end
 end
```

When I run the tests , it gives me this error :

```
 StaticPages Home page When signed in When no lists are present should show message asking to create list
     Failure/Error: sign_in user
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method visit' for #<SessionsController:0x00000003630c10>
     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:2:insign_in'
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:13:in create'
     # (eval):2:inclick_button'
     # ./spec/support/utilities.rb:5:in sign_in'
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:24:inblock (4 levels) in top (required)>'
```

This is "create" action of SessionsController :

```
def create
 user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
 if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
   sign_in user  # CODE ERRORS OUT HERE..sign_in of spec/support/utilities.rb executed
   redirect_back_or
 else
   flash.now[:error]= "Invalid email/password"
   render 'new' ,layout: "signin_fail"
 end
end
```

**TL,DR**: So, my SessionsController is executing the wrong "sign_in" method(the method which belongs to specs/support instead of app/helpers.session_helper.rb) . When I change the name of helper in spec/support to "log_in" , then the problem gets resolved . What could be the problem here ?

Comment: that's wired! how do you integrate spec utilities? is it a model or a class?

Comment: I just created a new spec/support directory and created a new "utilities.rb" file . I just defined the sign_in method in the file ,I did not declare it in a module/class . I understand that the functions inside 'utilities.rb' are autoloaded by rspec .

Comment: Thats how Michael Hartl's rails tutorial did it . And then it worked . Shouldn't the SessionsController look first in the SessionsHelper module ?

Comment: that totally depends on the load-order. having unscoped code in your app is a bad idea. just put it into a module and include that in the test where you need it.